# Center profile photo between top cover and left column

Tags: tailwind-css

I am trying to center the rounded full image between the main cover photo and the left column. For some reason I cannot get it to move from the top left corner and I cannot see what I am doing wrong. I am using Tailwind CSS.

```
<Head :title="profile.name" />
    <div class="relative w-full max-h-screen bg-gray-900 flex justify-start items-center rounded-lg">
        <div class="relative flex w-full h-48 bg-gray-700">
            <img :src="profile.cover_photo_path" class="cover-bg w-full "/>
            <div class="absolute inset-0 bottom-0 left-0">
                <img :src="profile.profile_photo_path" class="w-48 h-48 rounded-full border-2 border-red-600"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex flex-row">
        <!-- Left Column -->    
        <div class="bg-gray-900 w-1/3 h-96 z-0">

        </div>
        <!-- Right Column -->
        <div class="bg-gray-900 w-2/3 h-48 z-0">
            <div class="flex flex-row justify-between px-2 items-center h-12 border-b border-red-700">
                <div class="text-white text-center font-normal"> Feed </div>
                <div class="text-white text-center font-normal"> About </div>
                <div class="text-white text-center font-normal"> Photos </div>
                <div class="text-white text-center font-normal"> Videos </div>
                <div class="text-white text-center font-normal"> Events </div>
                <div class="text-white text-center font-normal"> Groups </div>
                <div class="text-white text-center font-normal"> Pages </div>
                <div class="text-white text-center font-normal"> Followers </div>
                <div class="text-white text-center font-normal"> Following </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Hi Can you please provide a minimum working example on tailwindcss playground. It will be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood , you want the circle rounded image in the middle of cover and left sidebar vertically and over them.

So I had created this ,please verify if you want. Else I would rather suggest  you to attach a screenshot of what you want .

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="relative flex max-h-screen w-full items-center justify-start rounded-lg bg-gray-900">
  <div class="relative flex h-48 w-full bg-gray-700">
    <img src="http://codeskulptor-demos.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/GalaxyInvaders/back05.jpg" class="cover-bg w-full" />
    <div class="absolute inset-0 top-1/2 left-10 z-10">
      <img src="http://codeskulptor-demos.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/pang/IHXoEES.png" class="h-48 w-48 rounded-full border-2 border-red-600" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="flex flex-row">
  <!-- Left Column -->
  <div class="z-0 h-96 w-1/3 bg-gray-900"></div>
  <!-- Right Column -->
  <div class="z-0 h-48 w-2/3 bg-gray-800">
    <div class="flex h-12 flex-row items-center justify-between border-b border-red-700 px-2">
      <div class="text-center font-normal text-white">Feed</div>
      <div class="text-center font-normal text-white">About</div>
      <div class="text-center font-normal text-white">Photos</div>
      <div class="text-center font-normal text-white">Videos</div>
      <div class="text-center font-normal text-white">Events</div>
      <div class="text-center font-normal text-white">Groups</div>
      <div class="text-center font-normal text-white">Pages</div>
      <div class="text-center font-normal text-white">Followers</div>
      <div class="text-center font-normal text-white">Following</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```